# Ubuntu Budgie: How to get rid of date on clock?

Tags: budgie, clock, applet

I just wanna get rid of the date option for the desktop clock called show time applet any ideas on how to? I cannot seem to find an option to remove the date from the clock

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and then, go to gnome-tweaks (typing it in a terminal)
go to  Top Bar > Flip-off Date at Clock